# How to read a file name from cmd that is opening the program?

Tags: java

Currently I have a program that starts and then asks for an command line input to open a file how would I go about it so when the program opens it can take something in that line as a parameter?

So I want to change it so when I start it in command  prompt and type

```
java program
fileName.txt    //program reads it via scanner(System.in)
```

To

```
java program fileName.txt  //program runs and takes the fileName.txt
```

Comment: in main function you get the String[] args. You can use the args for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you would use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String fileName = null;
  if (args.length > 0) {
    fileName = args[0].trim();
  }
  if (fileName != null) {
    // Do something....
  }
}
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).